# Haskell Parsec parser of Verilog-style number literals

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, verilog

I've set myself the task to write a function that parses Verilog-style number literals. In Verilog, numbers are written like this: 
`8'b10101100`, `16'hffff`, `'789`, `32'd0`, `12'o7`, etc.

The syntax is:

```
<size>'<radix>value
```

where `<...>` denotes an optional field, and

- `size` is the binary representation length of the number (in bits). The default is 32.
- `radix` is 'b' or 'B' for binary, 'o' or 'O' for octal, 'd' or 'D' for decimal, 'h' or 'H' for hexadecimal. The default is 'd'.
- `value` is the appropriate number representation for the given `radix`.

I'm new to Haskell, so I really would appreciate a critical appraisal of the following implementation. I think it is correct. Is it also 'good' Haskell/Parsec? Can it be done better, i.e. more concisely, more clearly, using more appropriate idioms?

```
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Data.Either (either)
import Data.Either.Extra (fromRight)
import Data.Char (digitToInt, toLower)
import Numeric (readInt, readOct, readHex)
import Text.Parsec.Combinator
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char (hexDigit, octDigit)

integerLog :: Integer -> Integer
integerLog = floor . logBase 2.0 . fromIntegral

-- |numberSize calculates the length (in bits) of the binary representation of Integer
numberSize :: Integer -> Integer
numberSize = (1+) . integerLog

-- |The type Number has a val (Integer value) and a len (binary representation length).
data Number = Number {val::Integer, len:: Integer} deriving Show

-- |makeNumber is a safe constructor of an Either String Number
makeNumber :: Integer -> Integer -> (Either String Number)
makeNumber v l
  | v < 0     = Left "makeNumber: Negative values not allowed in Number"
  | size > l  = Left $ "makeNumber: Value " ++ show v ++ " is " 
    ++ show size ++ " bits long, should be at most " ++ show l ++ " bits"
  | size <= 0 = Left $ "makeNumber: Size can't be negative or zero"
  | otherwise = Right $ Number v l
  where size = numberSize v

-- |readBin is not defined in Numeric (readInt, etc., are)
readBin = readInt 2 (`elem` "01") digitToInt

-- conversions String -> Number
hexToInteger x = fst $ readHex x !! 0 :: Integer
octToInteger x = fst $ readOct x !! 0 :: Integer
binToInteger x = fst $ readBin x !! 0 :: Integer

-- |binDigit is not in Text.Parsec.Char (hexDigit, octDigit are)
binDigit :: CharParser st Char
binDigit = oneOf "01"

-- |parse Verilog-style numbers <size>'<radix>value
parseNumber :: Parser Number
parseNumber = do
  size <- option "32" (many1 digit)
  char '\''
  radix <- option 'd' $ oneOf "hH" <|> oneOf "dD" <|> oneOf "oO" <|> oneOf "bB"
  let (thisDigit, convert_digits) =
        case toLower radix of
          'h' -> (hexDigit, hexToInteger)
          'o' -> (octDigit, octToInteger)
          'd' -> (digit   , read)
          'b' -> (binDigit, binToInteger)
          _  ->  error "parseNumber: Internal error"
  val <- many1 thisDigit
  let size' = read size :: Integer
      val' = convert_digits val :: Integer
      num = makeNumber val' size'
    in
    either fail return num


main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let results = map (parse parseNumber "parseNumber") args
  mapM_ print results
```

*Note: In true Verilog numbers have the format `<size>'<signed><radix>value` but in my application negative numbers are not allowed, hence the omission of `<signed>`.*

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time for a review, but here is some food for thought: `Int` (or even better `Word`) is more than enough for the number of bits, `logBase 2.0` might give the wrong result (starting at 1024 bits, see `zipWith (==) [0..] $ take 1500 $ map (floor . logBase 2) $ iterate (*2) 1`), and some functions are partial or violate DRY.

Comment: (Keep in mind that you should not change the code, though, even based on this comment, since someone might already write a complete answer; see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Good point, thanks for the input. 
The alternative could be to make numberSize safe by not using floats at all: 

      `numberSize = length $ takeWhile (>0) $ iterate (\`div\` 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your imports. You should get rid of those you don't need, e.g. `System.IO`, `import Data.Either.Extra (fromRight)`. Next, you shouldn't mix integral and floating point calculations, unless you're fine with imprecise results. For example, `integerLog` will give the wrong answer around `1024`:

```
ghci> integerLog (2^1023)
1023
ghci> integerLog (2^1024)
179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

Next, record field names are functions:

```
data Number = Number {val::Integer, len:: BitSize} deriving Show
```

This gives you two functions,

```
val :: Number -> Integer
len :: Number -> Integer
```

Unless you're fine with those functions at global namespace, it's usually a better idea to either a) use a complete name, e.g. `value`, `bitLength`, or b) prefix/suffix them with the type's name, e.g. `numberValue` or `lenNumber`. The story slightly changes if you want to use lenses and Template Haskell, but that's for another post.

What follows afterwards are several top-level functions without type signature, which is considered bad style:

```
readBin = readInt 2 (`elem` "01") digitToInt

-- conversions String -> Number
hexToInteger x = fst $ readHex x !! 0 :: Integer
octToInteger x = fst $ readOct x !! 0 :: Integer
binToInteger x = fst $ readBin x !! 0 :: Integer
```

All those functions are partial, e.g.

```
ghci> hexToInteger "Hello"
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large
```

Your use prevents this kind of error, since you're using it`hexToInteger` only on valid combinations, but you shouldn't export them either. That's not really an issue here since you've wrote a `Main (main)` module, but you should keep that in mind.

However, those functions would be a lot nicer with the appropriate type:

```
convertWith :: ReadS Integer -> String -> Maybe Integer
convertWith fn xs = case fn xs of
                      [(n,"")] -> Just n
                      _        -> Nothing

hexToInteger, octToInteger, binToInteger :: String -> Maybe Integer
hexToInteger = convertWith readHex
octToInteger = convertWith readOct
binToInteger = convertWith (readInt 2 (`elem` "01") digitToInt)
```

In this case we've dumped the plumbing into `convertWith`, added type signatures and made the functions non-partial. Now, let's step back to your smart-constructor:

```
-- |makeNumber is a safe constructor of an Either String Number
makeNumber :: Integer -> Integer -> (Either String Number)
makeNumber v l
  | v < 0     = Left "makeNumber: Negative values not allowed in Number"
  | size > l  = Left $ "makeNumber: Value " ++ show v ++ " is " 
    ++ show size ++ " bits long, should be at most " ++ show l ++ " bits"
  | size <= 0 = Left $ "makeNumber: Size can't be negative or zero"
  | otherwise = Right $ Number v l
  where size = numberSize v
```

While that's better than just a `Maybe Number`, it's still not optimal if you have an application that's creating those numbers. Since sum types aren't expensive to write, let's use one:

```
data NumberError = ENegative
                 | ENegativeSize
                 | EBitOverflow Integer Integer
 deriving (Show, Eq)
```

That way you can separate the formatting from the number handling:

```
makeNumber :: Integer -> BitSize -> (Either NumberError Number)
makeNumber v l
  | v < 0     = Left $ ENegative
  | size > l  = Left $ EBitOverflow v l
  | size <= 0 = Left $ ENegativeSize
  | otherwise = Right $ Number v l
  where size = numberSize v
```

You could also provide some functions, e.g.

```
eNegative    :: Either NumberError a
eBitOverflow :: Integer -> BitSize -> Either NumberError a
```

to ease the use of those, but that's an overkill here.

Speaking of overkills, did you notice the `BitSize` above? Many of your functions use `Integer -> Integer -> …`. But what do those `Integer`'s mean? Which one is the value? Which one is the bitsize? And is `Integer` as bitsize really a good idea?

Therefore, try to add some documentation at the type level, even if it isn't a new type:

```
type BitSize = Int
```

Now, let's have a look at the parser:

```
-- |parse Verilog-style numbers <size>'<radix>value
parseNumber :: Parser Number
parseNumber = do
  size <- option "32" (many1 digit)
  char '\''
  radix <- option 'd' $ oneOf "hH" <|> oneOf "dD" <|> oneOf "oO" <|> oneOf "bB"
  let (thisDigit, convert_digits) =
        case toLower radix of
          'h' -> (hexDigit, hexToInteger)
          'o' -> (octDigit, octToInteger)
          'd' -> (digit   , read)
          'b' -> (binDigit, binToInteger)
          _  ->  error "parseNumber: Internal error"
  val <- many1 thisDigit
  let size' = read size :: Integer
      val' = convert_digits val :: Integer
      num = makeNumber val' size'
    in
    either fail return num
```

This is well done, except for two minor quirks: you can collect all `oneOf <prefix>` parsers into a single one:

```
oneOf "hHdDoObB"
```

and your use of `error`, which makes this parser partial again. Instead, you could have used

```
  (thisDigit, convert_digits) <-
        case toLower radix of
          'h' -> return (hexDigit, hexToInteger)
          'o' -> return (octDigit, octToInteger)
          'd' -> return (digit   , read)
          'b' -> return (binDigit, binToInteger)
          _  ->  fail "parseNumber: Internal error"
```

Note that `parseNumber` slightly changes if you use `String -> Maybe Integer` from above (you should use `readMaybe` instead of `read` in this case). Also note that `parseNumber` isn't a good name in this case, it indicates that you're parsing, but you only define a parser. `numberParser` is usually slightly better.

Also, make sure that your variables follow the same naming convention. `convert_digits` kind of falls of the rest of your names.

Last but not least, it's strange that you get your numbers as arguments, e.g.

```
$ ./MyApplication 32\'b100101001
```

Usually, you take those values from `stdin` and print them to `stdout`. The `interact` function will come in handy.

## Bonus content: Separated concerns and an applicative `Parser`

So, now that we had a look at your code, how would I write it? I would probably introduce a function that takes the bitsize, the prefix, and the rest:

```
type BitSize      = Word
data NumberFormat = Bin | Oct | Dec | Hex

makeNumber :: BitSize -> NumberFormat -> String -> Either NumberError Number
makeNumber l d xs = do
  num <- readWith d xs
  case num of
   _ | num  < 0 -> eNegative
   _ | bits > l -> eBitOverflow num l
   _            -> return $ Number num l
  where num  = readWith d xs
        bits = fromIntegral $ numberSize num

readWith :: NumberFormat -> String -> Either NumberError Number
readWith d xs = maybeToEither $ case d of
                   Bin -> binToInteger xs
                   Oct -> octToInteger xs
                   Dec -> readMaybe    xs
                   Hex -> hexToInteger xs
```

Essentially that's still your code, only put into two functions and using the `NumberError` above. This makes it possible to later test the parts of your previously large `parseNumber`. Note that all those functions are rather small, and do only one thing (and one thing well).

Now what's left is the `Parser`. Instead of the previous `Monad` one, we can now easily use an `Applicative` one. For this, we provide three additional parsers that parse the sub-expressions `<bits>'<format><digits>`:

```
bitSizeParser :: Parser BitSize
bitSizeParser = option 32 $ fmap read $ many1 digits
-- read is fine here, since we use only digits

numberFormatParser :: Parser NumberFormat
numberFormatParser = option Dec $ fmap toFormat $ oneOf "hHoOdDbB"
  where toFormat c = case toLower c of
          'h' -> Hex
          'b' -> Bin
          'd' -> Dec
          'o' -> Oct

digitsParser :: Parser String
digitsParser = many1 $ oneOf "0123456789abcdef"
```

Now what's left is using those three parsers together and feeding them into `makeNumber`:

```
 import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>)) -- not needed in GHC 7.10 or higher

numberParser' :: Parser (Either NumberError Number)
numberParser' = 
  makeNumber <$> bitSizeParser <*> numberFormatParser <*> digitsParser

numberParser :: Parser Number
numberParser = numberParser' >>= either fail return
```

Note that the parts of our parser are now reasonably dumb. They only get things, i.e. `<bits>'<format><digits>`. The logic is now in `makeNumber`, which can be used without actually parsing, which might be handy if you want to check values from a database or similar.

Comment: Are the two `l`s in makeNumber supposed to collide? You didn't tell maybeToEither what NumberError to use. You could replace NumberFormat by (String -> Maybe Number) and everything would get shorter. (For that database testing thing to keep working, you could make toFormat :: Char -> (String -> Maybe Number) top-level.)

Comment: @Gurkenglas: No, that was a copy-error. Fixed it locally, but not in the online draft at that time. A small problem I see with `String -> Maybe Number` directly is that you're not able to print functions. Also, it's trivial to get `NumberFormat -> (String -> Maybe Number)`, but `(String -> Maybe Number) -> NumberFormat` is tricky (although possible, if we restrict the possible functions to the four above). But yeah, some of the code could get further improved. The bonus content is meant as a motivation, not a complete implementation.

Comment: @Zeta First of a all: This is a fantastic, in-depth review. Thank you! 
I'm with you all the way to the definition of your `makeNumber` in the bonus content. There, both the compiler and I fail on this `_ | num  < 0 -> ENegative`
construct. It's something to do with pattern guards for case alternatives...? I've been reading  about pattern guards, but I don't quite understand what this `_ | ...`  does. (By the way, a minor detail: `eNegative` should be `ENegative`, etc.)

Comment: @mcmayer: *"You could also provide some functions, e.g. `eNegative :: ...`"*. Those are handy if you want to change your errors later to `ErrorT` or back to `Maybe`. I'll have a look at the `case` later again, don't have a compiler atm

Comment: @mcmayer: Hm, just tried it. It should work. `case <expr> of [clause]` will try to bind` to the first pattern, where the (optional) guard is also `True`. Since the pattern is `_`, I'm only using guards here to check the number. A `MultiWayIf` would be slightly more clean, but I didn't want to introduce language extensions.